# How do I activate Depth of Field Preview on a Canon Eos 100?

Tags: canon, camera-settings, depth-of-field, old-cameras, dof-preview

I have searched the internet for some time now, and have found multiple mentions of a "depth of field preview" function on the Canon EOS 100 (the analog  one from 1991. I have used a Canon EOS 100 for quite some time now, did not stumble upon this function and find no reference of it in the camera's actual manual.

Can someone either confirm it exists or tell me how?

Comment: Did you try to enable custom function 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone either confirm it exists or tell me how?

Page 61 of [the EOS 100 user manual](https://www.manualslib.com/download/555553/Canon-Eos-100.html) explains how to set the various custom functions. There's a list of 7 different settings you can turn on, and (as @Gerhardh pointed out in a comment) custom function 5 lets you use the AE Lock button for depth of field preview. Here's the short version:

- Set the command dial to CF.
- Turn the main dial to select CF5.
- Press the AE Lock button so that the setting for CF5 changes from 0 to 1.

Now the AE Lock button should give you depth of field preview.

There's a complete list of the available settings on page 62.

Comment: Just the answer I needed thanks. I was under the false assumption of already having the Custom Functions ruled out.